# How to read formdata in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm using ionic angular in frontend and I' trying to send a  formdata that contains a file and also 2 strings. Apparently its being sent however I don't know how to read that information on the server side

**FRONTEND**

```
private fil3: File;
  changePicture(fileChangeEvent){//this functions is called by an input file
    this.fil3 = fileChangeEvent.target.files[0];
            
    let a1 = "a1"
    let a2 = "a2"

    let b1 = "b1"
    let b2 = "b2"

    let formData = new FormData();    

    formData.append('photo', this.fil3, this.fil3.name);
    formData.append(a1, a2);
    formData.append(b1, b2);
    
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/up', {
    method: 'POST', 
    body: formData, 
    headers:{
        /* 'Content-Type': 'application/json' */
        'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
    },
    mode: "cors",
  }).then(res =>{ res.json().then((data)=>{   

    console.log("filename: "+data.filename); 
    console.log("originalname: "+data.originalname); 
    console.log("message: "+data.message); 
    this.avatar="../../assets/uploads/"+data.filename
            
    })    
  }) 
  .catch(error => {console.error('Error:', error)})
  .then(response => {console.log(response)});
  }//changePicture
```

**SERVER**

```
 function updatePicture (req, res) {

   console.log("req.body: "+req.body)    

}
```

On the server side I'm just trying to read each element of the formdata individually so I can work with them. These elements are the file and two other strings(a1,a2,b1,b2). This console.log on the server prints this `req.body: [object Object]`

I tried things like

```
console.log("req.body: "+req.body.a1) 
console.log("req.body: "+req.body.[1])
```

but certainly do not work, I get `undefined`, I have no  idea how to handle this, any word of advice?

**MINIMUN REPRODUCIBLE CODE OF BACKEND**

```
const express = require ('express')
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser')
const app = express()
const api = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors')


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())



app.use(cors({
    origin: true
}));


const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(config.port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`)
})


api.post('/up', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body) 
})
```

Comment: Do console.log(req.body).

Comment: Have you set up a parsing middleware for formdata?

Comment: @MikeOne Thats the first thing I did, I put it on the server code above, I got [req.body: [object Object]] as an answer. eol I don't think i have done that, but is it really needed? I dont know how to console.log it in the front either, how do I get to see this data inside a FormData?

Comment: @rottenCoderSo Just `console.log(req.body)` not `console.log("req.body: "+req.body) ` as @MikeOne said because it is converted to string and data are hidden therefore.

Comment: @RAZAFINARIVOHanania interesting, I just did it and got this `{}`

Comment: @rottenCoderSo Do you use express lib?

Comment: @oel as parsing middleware im using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false}))` and `app.use(bodyParser.json())` only that

Comment: @RAZAFINARIVOHanania yes I do, I could bring any other piece of code if its needed, I tried to avoid putting extra code to not overload the thread

Comment: @rottenCoderSo Can you edit your post and add a minimum reproducible code for the backend part.

Comment: @RAZAFINARIVOHanania sure, I just did it you can check it out, I gathered every piece of code from diferent files. I also received this warninf from stackoverflow `Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?` I wouldn't like to get punished.

Comment: @rottenCoderSo My bad, i don't see you use `multipart/form-data`. It can't be parsed by `body-parser`. You need another library to do that.

Comment: you should place the middleware app.post before app.listen and it should be app., not api. plus you're doing `const api = express.Router()` twice. also body-parser is deprecated, use `express.urlencoded(...)` and `express.json(...)` those functions are now built in to express

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you for the `express.urlencoded(...)` and `express.json(...)` I didn't know about it, I just changed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, remove this part :

```
headers:{
    /* 'Content-Type': 'application/json' */
    'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
}
```

because if you define `Content-Type` manually, you can't inform about `boundary` information. It need to managed automatically by browser because you send files too.

Secondly, you need a library to parse you're multi-part data. You can use `formidable` :

```
const formidable = require('formidable');

//You're other codes

app.post('/up', (req, res) => {
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        console.log('fields: ', fields);
        console.log('files: ', files);
        res.send({ success: true });
    });
});
```

For my side this log something like :

```
fields:  { a1: 'a2', b1: 'b2' }
files:  {
file: PersistentFile {
    ...
```

Comment: Omg you're absolutely right sir it works like a charm. You are formidable, thank you

Comment: @rottenCoderSo You're welcome :)